# Cassandra 2.1 ERROR - LEAK DETECTED

Tags: cassandra, datastax-enterprise

I upgraded from Datastax Enterprise 4.5.1 to 4.7.3 yesterday. Now I see a few instances of this ERROR in system.log. I think this is happening during "nodetool repair".

`ERROR [Reference-Reaper:1] 2015-10-02 18:13:02,747 Ref.java:179 - LEAK DETECTED: a reference (org.apache.cassandra.utils.concurrent.Ref$State@312122cd) to class org.apache.cassandra.io.sstable.SSTableReader$InstanceTidier@1310889366:/data/lib/cassandra/data/reporting/summaries/snapshots/d7c61b70-6921-11e5-9215-6dd40f18e7fa/summaries-ka-1196 was not released before the reference was garbage collected`

Where should I start troubleshooting this error?

`[cqlsh 5.0.1 | Cassandra 2.1.8.689 | DSE 4.7.3 | CQL spec 3.2.0 | Native protocol v3]`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Nothing to troubleshoot.  It is a harmless issue, the leak detector fixed the problem.  The leak itself will be fixed by https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CASSANDRA-9998 the next time you upgrade.